# Can I dynamically add controls to backstage view in MSWord 2013?

Tags: ms-word

My basic question is the MS backstage view (for word 2013) static? Only visibility can be controlled or the action are being controlled in runtime - or I can add the controls dynamically in runtime.

I am stuck in the middle of building an application - which shall show the recent files in my customized backstage view.